# Which option contains the error? "(Will) you (help) me (to find) for my English notebook? (I'm tired)."

Tags: exam-questions

This is an error identification questions, one of the option contains an error.

> ***Will*** you ***help*** me ***to find*** for my English notebook? ***I'm tired.***
> (a) will
> (b) help
> (c) to find
> (d) I'm tired

I found nothing wrong with the sentence, can someone shed some light on this?

Comment: This is probably a better fit at [ell.se]. The only error I see is 'for my English book' - there should be no 'for'.

Comment: Maybe the expectation is that you should use 'look' instead of 'for'. "Will you help me __look for__ my notebook?" Note that it is more idiomatic to say here 'help me look for' instead of 'help me to look for' but the latter sounds perfectly fine.

Comment: The thing you want help with (***looking for*** or ***finding*** the book) is expressed as an ***infinitive***, but the "infinitive marker" is optional in such contexts. So apart from the fact that you can't include ***for*** with ***find***, you can also drop ***to***, giving *Will you help me **find my book**?* (where the object ***me*** is also entirely optional in most cases, because it's obvious speaker wants you to help ***him***, not to help someone else).

Comment: @FumbleFingers I think the "for" in the unmarked part of the sentence indicates the exercise is about distinguishing "look for" and "to find".

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it looks like a request for help with homework

Comment: Thanks Mitch, FumbleFingers and ColleenV :)

Comment: This is a question I have encountered in a test, I instinctively know it should b (c) but with no proper explanation. To tie the knot, the answer of the question is indeed c, hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

The verb "to find" being transitive requires a direct object. I.e. "Will you help me to find a battery for my notebook?", "What apology could she find for going back home?".

Comment: Thanks Eugene :)

Answer (score 1):

> Will You help me **to find** for my English notebook? I'm tired.

The error in this message is "to find". If not for that being in this sentence, this would be near correct.

Think about it this way; if you were to take out the word "Will", there is still an error in the sentence. If you were to take out the word "help", there is still an error in the sentence.

Either way for those two there is still an error so by process of elimination you have found your answer.

"Will You help me "to find" for my english notebook? I'm tired"
If you replace the "to find" with "find my pen" it would finally be correct.
'Will you help me find the pen for my english notebook?'
English should also be capitalized but that doesn't matter for this situation.

Comment: If not for "for" being in the sentence.

Comment: I suspect that they were intending that "to find" would actually be replaced with "to look" - _Will You help me to look for my English notebook?_. There's no need to introduce other objects such as a pen.

Comment: Thanks Lambie and Killing Time:)